# how to display record by id in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I wanto to display blog detail from database by clicking on specific blog item.I have created a controller and modal for that but no idea hot o display data by id in detail page.

Controller-

```
function blogContent(){
        $data['info'] = $this->auth_model->blogDetails($id);
        $popular['popular'] = $this->auth_model->getPopularcourses();
        $this->load->view('nulearnFront/blog_details', $data);
        $this->load->view('nulearnFront/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('nulearnFront/footer', $popular);
    }
```

Modal-

```
public function blogDetails($id) {
$q = $this->db->select('*')->from('blog')->where('id',$id)->get();
return $q->result();
}
```

but i've no idea how to display data by id on frontend. please check the above code also.

Comment: If you need only one row then use `$q->row()`

Comment: I want to display that parcular id data on which user clicks. when user clicks i want to open a page with description of that id

Comment: m not getting you what do you want from us? view code or what?

Comment: I actually want to fetch data from table of a single id at a time to display the data, belongs to that id

Comment: can you show `blog_details.php` from views folder and insted of `"*"` please mention column names in model then i can give you the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

You can add a route for the controller in the config/routes.php file like this:

```
$route['blog/(:any)'] = 'controller/blogContent/$1';
```

and modified controller

```
function blogContent($id){
    $data['info'] = $this->auth_model->blogDetails($id);
    $popular['popular'] = $this->auth_model->getPopularcourses();
    $this->load->view('nulearnFront/blog_details', $data);
    $this->load->view('nulearnFront/header', $data);
    $this->load->view('nulearnFront/footer', $popular);
}
```

after that, you should only create a correct link to a blog, like this:

```
<a href="blog/1">My Blog</a>
```

and you should get blog id in your controller